# Use intel chip on systems with two graphics chips

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have a computer with two graphics chips.  For reference, one is the Nvidia GTX 670, and the other is the integrated graphics on the Intel 3770k.

When I pull out the NVidia card, Ubuntu uses the Intel Graphics chip just fine.  However, when I put in the card, it seems to insist on using the NVidia one.  Even with the closed source drivers though, the Intel chip works significantly better for general desktop usage.  So is there any way I can have ubuntu use the Intel chip rather than the NVidia one even when the nvidia card is plugged in?  (Also, if it's possible, although not really necessary I would also like to be able to have it switch to the nvidia card when requested).

(If you are wondering why I bought the card when I'm not planning on using it, I do use it on windows, and ideally I would like to use it for scientific computing/visualization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked in to [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)? Ubuntu with hybrid-graphics is a pain to get setup, and usually doesn't work well. However, I think installing bumblebee would fix your problem. When you install it you can use `optirun` for any programs you want on the graphics card.